# Quantidade total de valores em array PHP

Tags: php

Tenho essa `array` abaixo, e gostaria de saber como posso contar quantos valores iguais tem no `value[0]`.

Array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "500038"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "204932"
"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "500038"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "204932"
"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "100398"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "204932"
"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "100398"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "204932"
"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "100398"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "204932"
"
  }
}
```

Por exemplo sei que possui 2 valores iguais que são `500038` e 3 que são `100398`. Preciso do total de ambos. Os números no `value[0]` vão variar nem sempre sendo os mesmo.

Gostaria de uma forma para fazer isso pois preciso destes números para saber a quantidade total e o número do volume.

A minha ideia seria isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar a função `array_count_values`. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @EduardoBreno pelo que entendi ele quer verificar apenas do `value[0]`

Comment: @MauroAlexandre, certo... hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se lhe atende.

```
<?php

$array[] = array(500038, 204932);
$array[] = array(100398, 204932);
$array[] = array(100398, 204932);
$array[] = array(500038, 204932);
$array[] = array(100398, 204932);


for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $volume[$i] = $array[$i][0];
}

$volumeContado = array_count_values($volume);

foreach ($volumeContado as $key => $value) {
    $novoArray[] = array("volume" => $key, "qtd" => $value);
}

var_dump($novoArray);
```

Saída.

```
 array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'volume' => int 500038
      'qtd' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'volume' => int 100398
      'qtd' => int 3
```

Comment: Perfeito. Tem como adaptar ao código dele. Imagine o seguinte array `$array = array(
 0 => array("500038", "204932"),
 1 => array("100398", "204932"),
 2 => array("500038", "204932"),
 3 => array("100398", "204932"),
 4 => array("500038", "204932"),
 5 => array("50003", "204932"),
 6 => array("50003845", "204932"),
);`

Comment: Como eu manipulo estes dados ? Tem como eu armazenar em uma váriavel ?

Comment: @Kevin.F,você pode atribuir o resultado para uma variavel `$contados = array_count_values($contar);`

Comment: @Kevin.F, editei o código para deixar mais simples, removei o volume do indice para ser mais fácil trabalhado.

Comment: @EduardoBreno ok, é que após isso vou colocar estes dados num txt e importar para o db. Mas vlw era isso mesmo.